# Can not INSERT data to my sqlite3 database. (Iphone)

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, insert

I have a problem with writing down some data into my sqlite3 database. The problem is that during the app is working on simulator, after the INSERT i am checking it out by SELECT and i am able to see my new data in database. But after am switching of the app i am loosing my data. I thought that i dont have a law to write down  data on this file but i checked it and i have it.

When i am working on my divice i can see data which were in my database but when i am using INSERT nothing happens.

Has anyone the same problem ? could anybody help my to deal with this ?

hear is the code of the INSERT

```
NSString *insertStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO person (uniqueId, idn, heartP, sugar, data) VALUES (\"%i\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\");", uniqueIds, idns, heartPs, sugars, datas];

if(sqlite3_exec(database, [insertStatement UTF8String],NULL ,NULL ,nil)==SQLITE_OK){


    NSLog(@"well done");
}
```

}

Comment: I dont know using 2 lines how you insert in your sqlite.from next time please post your full code so other can understand that.

Comment: sory dude i added ony that part coz i didnt asking of how to create database or how to open database. Im doing it correct so i only paste that part where someone may see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think you database was not copy in document directory.

Comment: yep its not, this may be the answer of  the second part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code and check what mistake you have done.i am using this code only this will work for me.

```
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &adddata) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    // NSLog(@"open");
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO contacts(FirstName,LastName,Company,Mobile,Home,Url,Street,City,State,Zip,Prefix,Suffix,Middle,JobTitle,Birthday,Note) VALUES (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")", firstName.text,lastName.text,companyName.text,mobileNumber.text,homeNumber.text,homeUrl.text,street.text,city.text,state.text,zip.text,prefix.text,suffix.text,middle.text,jobTitle.text,birthday.text,note.text];

    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

    int c=sqlite3_prepare_v2(adddata, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
    NSLog(@"%d",c);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"alert" message:@"Data is added" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
        [alert show];
        NSLog(@"%@",insertSQL);
        firstName.text = @"";

    } 
    else 
    {
        alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"alert" message:@"Data is not added" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
        [alert show];                 
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(adddata);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't write to your app bundle even if you have write permissions for that file. You need to move the file to the Library, Documents or tmp directory.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
NSString *insertStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO person (uniqueId, idn, heartP, sugar, data) VALUES (\"%i\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\");", uniqueIds, idns, heartPs, sugars, datas];

sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [insertStatement UTF8String],-1, &selectstmt, NULL);

       if(sqlite3_step(selectstmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"insert successfully");
        }
```

Comment: it only insert statement to store data in DB